# How to show overlay with pure JavaScript on modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to make a modal with JavaScript ES5.

When you click a button, an overlay will show, and a modal window. The modal window will have an 'X' (close modal), which will remove the overlay and the modal. If you click the modal, nothing happens; if you click the X or overlay it hides.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried many things, however whenever I try to put my modal with the overlay the code stops working.

And do you see any way to improve the current code as well? Staying very basic.

```js
// Click button
// Show overlay
// Show Modal - text and close button

// Click overlay - close
// Click button - close overlay
// Click modal - no effect

//Variables
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn-overlay');
var overlay = document.createElement = ('<div class="overlay"></div>');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
var closeBtn = document.querySelector('.modal-close');

function showModal(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  modal.classList.add('is-active');
  document.body.appendChild(overlay);
}

function closeModal(e) {
  modal.classList.remove('is-active');
  document.body.removeChild(overlay);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', showModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 8000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
}

.modal.is-active {
  display: block;
}

.modal-close {
  position: relative;
  cusror: pointer;
  z-index: 9950;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Awesome content</h1>
  <button class="btn-overlay"> Show Modal</button>
</main>

<section class="modal">
  <span class="modal-close">X</span>
  <h1>Modal</h1>
</section>
```

[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/KZQrBB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `document.createElement` correctly. The method expects an argument—the type of element you wish to create.

```
// Create a div
var overlay = document.createElement('div');
// Assign a class name
overlay.className = 'overlay';
```

Though this next bit wasn't breaking your code, you should fix the typo in your `CSS`:

```
.modal-close {
  …
  cusror: pointer; /* <-- oops */
  …
}
```

Finally, you asked about suggestions to improve the code. I would read about how to make your modal code accessible. Accessibility is too often ignored when we make stuff and making your pixels work for everyone is critical. Have a look at [this](https://bitsofco.de/accessible-modal-dialog/) for examples and deep explanations. Apart from accessibility, I would consider adding a transition to your overlay and making it a pseudo element on the `body`. The advantage is cleaner code and less `JavaScript`.

```js
// Click button
  // Show overlay
  // Show Modal - text and close button

// Click overlay - close
// Click button - close overlay
// Click modal - no effect

  //Variables
  var btn = document.querySelector('.btn-overlay');
  var overlay = document.createElement('div');
  overlay.className = 'overlay';
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  var closeBtn = document.querySelector('.modal-close');
  

  function showModal(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.add('is-active');
    body.appendChild(overlay);
  }

  function closeModal(e) {
    modal.classList.remove('is-active');
    document.body.removeChild(overlay);
  }
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', showModal);
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 8000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
}

.modal.is-active {
  display: block;
}

.modal-close {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9950;
}
```

```html
<body>
<main>
  
  <h1>Awesome content</h1>
  
  <button class="btn-overlay"> Show Modal</button>
  
  
</main>
  
  <section class="modal">
    <span class="modal-close">X</span>
    <h1>Modal</h1>
  </section>
  
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y0wfzuj8/

Comment: I see. Yeah, I though about accessibility, but right now I'm trying to learn programming logic and JS, then get more into accessibility as there is too much at once. Do you think what I did here is ok? Can I write a blog post on how I did it? Perhaps I can then or now add accessibility to it, and then write a blog post about it - https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/KZQrBB trying to learn js by building daily components

Comment: If I were you, I would create a separate (new) question about how to improve the code over in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you want to hold off on the accessibility portion when writing the blog post, fine, but I would at least improve the look and feel of the demo. People like looking at attractive demos. Use a more attractive font and make sure content is centered perfectly and works on desktop & mobile. Maybe tell people at the end of the post that there will be a part 2 which covers accessibility.

Comment: Another thing I thought of as a way to improve the code is to make it function with multiple click targets (buttons). This would be very useful for beginners who might implement your code into their work.

Comment: That's a gread idea! Will definitelly do that! Do you mean to have like 5modals on the page and see if they will work? I guess I need to put in the id or match the class or something. Hmm, maybe that's more prototyping in JS. Hmmm, well, still learning :D Carousel/Slider is a big one, I'm preparing my self for that one with these little challenges like the modal, tabs etc... didn't yet manage to do a slider.

Comment: I guess I can put the re-factoring her, since they said that re-factoring and improving on the code in the 'Code Review' section is off-topic eh. Said the code can be broken, when it's not lol - https://codepen.io/lovetocodex/pen/mpxmjY?editors=1010

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code review? If they won't help improve it, maybe post a new question here and ask the community for guidance.

Comment: I'v made a new one here on stackoverflow, I got 1hour left before midnight, and before that time I need to upload my blog post - I wrote some stuff but yeah. If not I'll just go with what I currently have xd It's still learning. By writing blog posts I understand a lot more what's happening as I gotta explain it to my self and understand the functions/methods etc ... I love this! lol now I'm really learning so id use stack to the advantage as well :D

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194875/functional-javascript-programming-making-a-modal-a-popup-and-refactoring-it/48195127#48195127